# How create font table for Computer Modern typewriter style?

Tags: fonts

What is the correct form of the `\xfonttable` (or other) command from the
`fonttable` package to produce the font table for Computer Modern Roman typewrite font?

Comment: `\xfonttable{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}`? Or `\xfonttable{T1}{cmtt}{m}{n}` for T1 encoding